# fill missing value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill the column of a dataframe as shown in example.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','','','a','','b','b','','b','']})
```

[image: current df]

i want to replace the empty values between two rows having same value:
output:

[image]

Can we do it without iterrows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First replace empty strings to missing values and then compare forward and backfilling values and use only matched values:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','','','a','','b','b','','b','']})

s = df.A.replace('', np.nan)

s1 = s.ffill()
s2 = s.bfill()

df.A = s1.where(s1.eq(s2), '')
print (df)
   A
0  a
1  a
2  a
3  a
4   
5  b
6  b
7  b
8  b
9
```